# Bove-Capretta Predicate in Prop

Tags: recursion, agda, dependent-type

The Bove-Capretta method ([http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszvc/publications/General_Recursion_MSCS_2005.pdf](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszvc/publications/General_Recursion_MSCS_2005.pdf)) is a neat trick for modelling non-structurally recursive or partial functions in languages like Agda. Terminating inputs to a function are characterised by an inductive predicate, and the function is rewritten to take the predicate as an argument.

For example, suppose we wanted to write the following definition of a base-2 logarithm in Agda (using module `Data.Nat`):

```
log2 : ℕ → ℕ
log2 0 = 0
log2 1 = 0
log2 n = suc (log2 ⌊ n /2⌋)
```

Unfortunately, this definition does not pass the termination checker. Following Bove-Capretta, one could define the following predicate:

```
data Loggable : ℕ → Set where
    log-n≡0 : Loggable 0
    log-n≡1 : Loggable 1
    log-n≡n : ∀ {n} → Loggable ⌊ n /2⌋ → Loggable n
```

And then augment the original definition to take `Loggable` as an extra argument:

```
log2 : (n : ℕ) → Loggable n → ℕ
log2 0 _ = 0
log2 1 _ = 1
log2 n (log-n≡n p) = suc (log2 ⌊ n /2⌋ p)
```

This now successfully passes the termination checker, since the `Loggable` predicate serves as the structurally decreasing argument. This all works as expected.

Now, since the predicate is solely used to convince the termination checker, it would make sense to move it to the sort `Prop` since it should not have any computational effect. Indeed, inspecting our new definition of `log2` also suggests this, since the predicate is not used to make any case splits that have not already been determined by the other argument.

This is where the problem is. Firstly, making `Loggable` a `Prop` prohibits case splitting on it when we are producing something in sort `Set`, which is the case in our new `log2` function. The normal solution to this is to introduce an auxiliary "inversion lemma" operating in the sort `Prop`, which destructs the predicate and extracts the part we need. Unfortunately, this introduces a new problem - the structural termination of `log2` would be broken, since Agda cannot see the result of calling the "inversion lemma" is structurally smaller than its input.

*(Note that an equivalent of this problem can be written in Coq, which does not suffer from the same issue as it normalises expressions before checking for termination, and hence the proposes "inversion lemma" approach succeeds.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `Prop` in Coq (but like `sProp`), Agda's `Prop` universe supports *definitional proof irrelevance*. This means that any two elements of a type in `Prop` are definitionally equal to the conversion checker. On the other hand, this also means that evaluation of a term can never get stuck on an argument of a type in `Prop`, and hence these arguments cannot be used to prove termination. So unfortunately, this means **the Bove-Capretta method does not work with Agda's `Prop` universe.**